# My header div wont scroll

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a problem with my header it seems like the position is fixed, and it wont scroll.

```
     header.masthead {
     position: initial;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: auto;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     overflow:scroll;
     background-position: center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover; }"
```

Comment: add your code to see the problem

Comment: I think you need to set a height

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments, you should set a height of div. You could set it with pixels, ems, or something else. Without a specified height, your content will simply enlarge header, without scrolling.

[Test live, version 1](https://jsfiddle.net/btnzbetv/)

[Test live, version 2, better](https://jsfiddle.net/btnzbetv/2/)

Also, take a look at min-height and max-height.

```
<header class="masthead">
     <p>I'm a header</p>
     <p>I'm a header</p>
     <p>I'm a header</p>
     <p>I'm a header</p>
     <p>I'm a header</p>
</header>

<style>
header.masthead {
     position: initial;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: auto;
     text-align: center;
     color: red;
     overflow: scroll;
     background-position: center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     height: 3em;
}

header.masthead p {
     margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the height.

See the snippet:

```css
   .masthead {
     position: initial;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: auto;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     overflow:scroll;
     background-position: center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover; 
     background: red;
     height: 200px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="masthead">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to set fix height to your header div and then apply the CSS for header div as

```css
overflow : auto
```

or

```css
overflow : scroll
```